# How to find out if XML element comes after another?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

Here's the sample code:

XML

```
<docbody>
    <p>This is the main paragraph</p>
        <ul>This is a list element!</ul>
        --{add thousands of lines of code}--
    <a name='#r1'>Hello</a>
    <p>Footnotes begin</p>
        <ul>This text should be rendered right below footnote</ul>
</docbody>
```

This would seem fine. However, the XSLT code that I have which transforms this XML file adds the class "paragraphtext", which forces any text within the `<ul>` element into the paragraph, and not right below the footnote as I need it.

To sum up, I need the second `<ul>` element in the sample to stay below the footnote, and not be forced into the paragraph as per its class given (I cannot change the CSS or any classes for that matter).

The way I thought I could do this is to somehow detect the position of the second `<ul>` element - though both of these elements have the same parent, *but* one thing that may help is the fact that the `<a name="#r1">` element only and always precedes the footnote section - it can never be found in the document body section.

Therefore, I thought if there would be a way to test if the `<ul>` element comes *after* the `a` element with the name that `starts-with[@name, '#r1']`, but it seems that the `position()` function takes no arguments?

So, is there a way to somehow "detect" the position of the `a` element and compare it to the position of the `ul` element? Thanks.

**EDIT**:

The XSLT that I have is 10 000 lines of code, but here's the relevant section:

```
  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="'paragraphtext'" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

The text that I am currently getting:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae
>   dolor cursus, aliquet purus eget, placerat augue. Morbi blandit, risus
>   ac dignissim dapibus, lectus ipsum venenatis augue, a malesuada magna
>   purus et quam. Curabitur tincidunt eleifend orci, et tempor nunc
>   laoreet at. Nullam vitae mauris nisi. **Footnote body goes here
>   instead of after the relevant footnote.**
>
> **FOOTNOTES**
>
> (1) Reference 1
>
> (2) Reference 2

The text that I **want** to get:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae
>   dolor cursus, aliquet purus eget, placerat augue. Morbi blandit, risus
>   ac dignissim dapibus, lectus ipsum venenatis augue, a malesuada magna
>   purus et quam. Curabitur tincidunt eleifend orci, et tempor nunc
>   laoreet at. Nullam vitae mauris nisi.
>
> **FOOTNOTES**
>
> (1) Reference 1
>
> ```
> **Footnote body goes here  - this is the correct way**
> ```
>
> (2) Reference 2

Comment: Could you share the XSLT you have already and an example of the output you want? That would be easier to understand than prose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preceding-sibling` axis.

To directly select the 2nd ul:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/docbody/ul[preceding-sibling::ul]"/>
```

To use in for loop with condition:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/docbody/ul">
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(preceding-sibling::ul)">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the **preceding-sibling** axis here, to test (for the matched **ul** element) whether there is a preceding sibling matching your criteria

```
 <xsl:template match="ul">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::a[starts-with(@name, '#r1')]">Do stuff</xsl:if>
```

But it would actually be cleaner if your wrote this as a separate template match

```
 <xsl:template match="ul[preceding-sibling::a[starts-with(@name, '#r1')]]">
```

Where you have an element match with extra conditions, XSLT will give priority to the one with conditions. So, for the **ul** element following the **a**, the second template would always be used.

The two templates would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
    <div class="paragraphtext">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[preceding-sibling::a[starts-with(@name, '#r1')]]">
  <div class="Hurrah">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that there is no need to use **xsl:attribute** in creating you class attribute. Just write it out directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution once again, Tim! I have no doubts that it works, but unfortunately it seems that in my document all the `ul` tags are rendered BEFORE all of the `a` tags... I have no idea what to grab now.